# Призрачный CSS (разные стили для одной страницы)

Tags: хостинг

Всем доброго времени суток.

Чем отличается ввод страницы с ***www*** в начале от отсутствия ***www***? Пример: *www.mysite.ru* и *mysite.ru*. У меня для них почему-то стили разные грузятся на хостинге (без *www* - тот, который был до этого). Хотя стиль один.

Comment: По все вероятности у вас при подключении .css используются абсолютные пути.. что за система? самописный сайт? дайте ссылку

Comment: Технически - это два разных домена. Соответсвенно, могут грузиться "разные" файлы в зависимости от того, прописаны ли пути относительные или абсолютные. И тут могут быть вариации с кэшированием на стороне сервера.

Comment: @Arsen, нет, используются относительные пути. Самописный сайт. Хостинг (zzz.com.ua).(www.testbirdhunter.zzz.com.ua)

Comment: @br3t, прописаны относительные, но прописаны правильно. Понимаю, что два разных домена, но кто в www, в таком случае, закинул предыдущий стиль? А что насчёт кэширования (это я не очень понял)?

Comment: Кэширование на сервере могло быть актуально, если бы пути были абсолютными. Я вижу одинаковый внешний вид на страничке с www и без. У вас они разные?

Comment: Интересно, на www курсор над пунктами меню не превращается в pointer - вы про это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После просмотра ссылки `http://testbirdhunter.zzz.com.ua/` и `http://www.testbirdhunter.zzz.com.ua/` я в стилях никакой разницы не увидел, т.е стили не меняются. Возможно у вас проблема в кешировании браузера, напримиер вы написали несколько стилей при открытом домене через `www`, потом через некоторое время написали новые стили без `www` вот и браузер 'запомнил' так. Можете удалить все старые кеши из браузера и заново проверить.

Comment: Да, всё помогло. Спасибо. А как бороться с тем, чтобы больше такого не запоминал?

Comment: @IvanLazarev Обновляйте страницу через Ctrl+F5

Comment: @br3t, спасибо. Буду использовать. Очень помогли. А я, видимо, в гугле неправильный запрос составлял, раз ответа не нашёл.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 вам в помощь ), так же я бы посоветовал сделать редирект 301 (без www на www) через  .htacces для оптимального SEO

Comment: @br3t каждого посетителя сайта трудно заставить нажать Ctrl+F5. Особенно на мобильных телефонах, где нет ни Ctrl, ни F5 :)

Comment: @Arsen, А чем вариант с лишним субдоменом предпочтительнее(в плане SEO)?

Comment: @vp_arth перезагрузка страницы методом Ctrl+F5 это для моментального обновления информации в браузере (заново отправляется запрос на сервер и приходит новая инфа), посетителям это не надо (если они прямо в минуту редактирования css не зашли на сайт) через некоторое время браузер сам обращается на сервер для получения новой инфы структуры сайта и посетитель видит новые стили.
"с лишним субдоменом предпочтительнее"  - вы это о чём ? о www ? но это не субдомен.. если я правильно понял о чём вы

Comment: Ой, как много. Я только спросил почему вы предлагаете редирект `site.com` -> `www.site.com`, а не наоборот.

Comment: теоритически нет разницы, главное чтобы всегда домен был или с www или без  www, но практика показывает что лучше  с WWW (!) ИМХО )

Comment: @Arsen это «некоторое время» временами доходит до полугода, так что всё-таки лучше настроить параметры кэширования со стороны сервера

Comment: А субдомен www не нужен и в 2017 ему бы пора уже прекратить своё существование.

Comment: @andreymal , есть способы (заголовки кеширования для браузера, да и старый добрый `style.css?v=123456` никто не отменял), но я так понял, что проблема имеет место только для разработчика, а для пользователя, как верно заметил @Arsen, проблемы не будет.

Comment: @br3t только вот эти способы надо не забыть применить, а то даже у ВК с этим проблемы)